# Can't change DNS at GoDaddy

Tags: dns, godaddy

I just registered a domain at GoDaddy and wanted to change the DNS server to my (soon to be) host.

I followed [this tutorial](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names), section "Setting Custom Nameservers for a Domain Name Registered with Us" (my domain is registered with GoDaddy but should be hosted elsewhere).

Step 4

> "From the Nameservers menu, select Set Nameservers"

works, but I can't continue with step 5

> "Under Setup type, select Custom"

since the pop-up window does not show any options. Only the "cancel" button works, while the "save" button is inactive:

[image: GoDaddy: No options displayed]

What is the problem here and how can I fix it? I registered the domain an hour ago - do I need to wait a bit?

Comment: I would contact godaddy their might be something about your domain special I can confirm the tutorial is correct

Comment: Ok, I created a support ticket.